# How import module as class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I had a problem when I wanted to create my factory.

I have a directory that looks like that:

```
classes/
     file_1.py
     file_2.py
     ....
factory.py
```

In `file_1` and `file_2`, i have some classes definition in like this:

```
class A():
    ...

class B():
    ...
```

In `factory.py` i want create a class on which I could use `getattr` function.

I tried to do that:

```
from classes import file_1, file_2

class Factory(file_1, file_2):
    """doctring"""

def build(dic):
    factory = Factory()
    return getattr(dic['name'], factory)(**dic['params'])
```

But `file_1` and `file_2` are module, not a class.

So what are the other ways that I can use to make my factory ?
And if there are several, which is the best ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research and discussions, I finally found a solution.

i added a `__init__` in `classes/` folder :

```
classes/
     __init__.py
     file_1.py
     file_2.py
     ....
factory.py
```

And in this file i added a `from classes.file_1 import *` for each file.

So, in `factory.py` i just do:

```
import classes

def build(dic):
    return getattr(classes, dic['name'])(**dic['params']))
```

I do not know if this is the best way but it's work fine.
Thanks to you two @enamoria and @Norrius

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
from classes.file_1 import class_in_file_1
```

Note that if you're using `python2`, then you need to create `__init__.py` file in `classes` directory. No problem if that file is empty

Comment: it's not what I want, I have a lot of classes in my files and i want to call it according to his name, but if i do ``class Factory(A, B, C):`` it does not put classes in attribute of the Factory object.

Comment: So you want to import all `A, B, C` so your `Factory` can inherit all of them? I don't really get your point

Comment: I do not want `Factory` to inherit from A, B, C, ...
I would like A, B, C, ... to be a `Factory` attribute, as if I had inherited the file

Comment: @iElden Could you explain what you mean by "inheriting" a file?

Comment: @Norrius I would like classes that are in my `file` to work as attributes of `file`. Which would allow me to use getattr to easily have the class I want.

Comment: @iElden Okay. First thing: [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) takes an object and a string. In the question, you use a `Factory` as the second argument, which is not going to work. Second thing: you can make `A` and `B` a class variable or an instance variable on `Factory`, see [this article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). Last thing: what you are describing honestly doesn't make much sense and might be not the best design choice.

Comment: I will try to rephrase my question. : I have several classes in a file, and I get a dictionary with the name of the class and the parameters that I have to send. What is the best way to get the class given by the name ?

Comment: @iElden You could put them in a dict, where the key is a name and the value is the class for that name.

Comment: Technically your answer is just like mine, since `__init__` will import class beforehand, while my answer suggest import it in the beginning of `factory.py`